# algorithm on optimization binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am reading about optimal BST algorithm at

http://www.cs.yorku.ca/~andy/courses/3101/lecture-notes/OptBST.pdf

Here on page 3 author mentioned as below

> More specifically, we start the induction with minimum cost trees each
>   of which contains exactly one key, and proceed by constructing minimum
>   cost trees with 2, 3, . . . , n successive keys. Note that there are
>   exactly n - d +1 groups of d successive keys for each d = 1, . . . ,
>   n. Thus, instead of considering all possible trees with n nodes we
>   consider only n (minimum cost) trees with 1 node each, n -1 (minimum
>   cost) trees with 2 nodes each, . . ., 1 minimum cost tree with n
>   nodes, i.e. a total of n(n +1)/2 trees.

On above text

1. What does author mean by "there are there are exactly n - d +1 groups" ?
2. Another question what does author mean by (n-1) minimum cost trees with 2 nodes, n-2 minimum cost trees with 3 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems d is count of nodes (keys) in group;

so if there is 1 node in group, there are n groups;

if there are 2 nodes in group, n - 2 + 1 = n - 1 groups

n nodes in group: n - n + 1 = 1 group